# Unable to forward port 443 using Static NAT on Cisco 1921

Tags: cisco, router, nat

I have configured Static NAT to forward port 443 to 192.168.0.3 internal IP address as follows:

```
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.3 443 interface Dialer1 443
```

However, I see "Page Not Found" when I try to access it with a web browser over port 443 (internally and externally). I have also checked online port forward tester that port 443 is closed. I don't have any issue accessing server on 443 internally.

P.S. I am not Cisco expert and this router has been configured by previous IT guys so I might not know everything configured in this config.

Please see following config:

```
INTGATEWAY#sh conf
Using 6037 out of 262136 bytes
!
! Last configuration change at 15:46:10 Sydney Tue Aug 6 2013 by admin.cisco
! NVRAM config last updated at 16:13:31 Sydney Tue Aug 6 2013 by admin.cisco
! NVRAM config last updated at 16:13:31 Sydney Tue Aug 6 2013 by admin.cisco
version 15.1
service tcp-keepalives-in
service tcp-keepalives-out
service timestamps debug datetime msec localtime
service timestamps log datetime msec localtime
service password-encryption
service sequence-numbers
!
hostname INTGATEWAY
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker
!
!
no logging buffered
enable secret 5 Secret...Shhhh....
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authentication ppp V_USERS group radius
aaa authorization network V_USERS group radius
!
!
!
!
!
aaa session-id common
!
clock timezone Sydney 10 0
clock summer-time Sydney date Mar 30 2003 3:00 Oct 26 2003 2:00
!
no ipv6 cef
ip source-route
ip cef
!
!
!
!
!
no ip domain lookup
ip domain name domain.com.au
ip name-server 203.12.160.35
ip name-server 203.12.160.36
ip inspect max-incomplete high 800
ip inspect max-incomplete low 600
ip inspect name FIREWALL ftp
ip inspect name FIREWALL h323
ip inspect name FIREWALL netshow
ip inspect name FIREWALL rcmd
ip inspect name FIREWALL realaudio
ip inspect name FIREWALL rtsp
ip inspect name FIREWALL smtp
ip inspect name FIREWALL sqlnet
ip inspect name FIREWALL streamworks
ip inspect name FIREWALL tftp
ip inspect name FIREWALL tcp
ip inspect name FIREWALL udp
ip inspect name FIREWALL vdolive
ip inspect name FIREWALL icmp
ip inspect name FIREWALL isakmp
ip inspect name FIREWALL ipsec-msft
!
multilink bundle-name authenticated
!
vpdn enable
!
vpdn-group COMPANY_VPN
! Default L2TP VPDN group
accept-dialin
  protocol l2tp
  virtual-template 1
no l2tp tunnel authentication
!
crypto pki token default removal timeout 0
!
crypto pki trustpoint TP-self-signed-4155725390
enrollment selfsigned
subject-name cn=IOS-Self-Signed-Certificate-4155725390
revocation-check none
rsakeypair TP-self-signed-4155725390
!
!
crypto pki certificate chain TP-self-signed-4155725390
certificate self-signed 01 nvram:IOS-Self-Sig#1.cer
license udi pid CISCO1921/K9 sn FGL153820V4
!
!
username administrator privilege 15 password 7 Administrator_Password
username admin.cisco privilege 15 password 7 Cisco_Admin_Password
!
redundancy
!
!
!
!
no ip ftp passive
ip ssh time-out 60
ip ssh port 2222 rotary 1
ip ssh version 2
!
!
crypto isakmp policy 10
encr 3des
authentication pre-share
group 2
crypto isakmp key PreSharedKey address 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0
!
!
crypto ipsec transform-set VPN esp-3des esp-sha-hmac
mode transport
!
crypto dynamic-map VPN-map 10
set nat demux
set transform-set VPN
reverse-route
!
!
crypto map VPN 10 ipsec-isakmp dynamic VPN-map
!
!
!
!
!
interface Embedded-Service-Engine0/0
no ip address
shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
description COMPANY LAN
ip address 192.168.0.253 255.255.255.0
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
load-interval 30
duplex auto
speed auto
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/1
description TPG INTERNET EFM SERVICE
no ip address
ip access-group OUTSIDE_IN in
load-interval 30
duplex auto
speed auto
pppoe enable group global
pppoe-client dial-pool-number 1
!
interface Virtual-Template1
ip unnumbered GigabitEthernet0/0
ip nat inside
ip virtual-reassembly in
peer default ip address dhcp
ppp encrypt mppe auto
ppp authentication ms-chap-v2 V_USERS
ppp authorization V_USERS
!
interface Dialer1
mtu 1492
ip address negotiated
ip nat outside
ip inspect FIREWALL out
ip virtual-reassembly in
encapsulation ppp
dialer pool 1
dialer idle-timeout 0
dialer persistent
dialer-group 1
ppp pap sent-username USERNAME@TPG.COM.AU password 7 iNTERNET_PASSWORD
crypto map VPN
!
ip forward-protocol nd
!
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
!
ip nat inside source list NAT interface Dialer1 overload
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.2 80 interface Dialer1 80
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.3 443 interface Dialer1 443
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.2 25 interface Dialer1 25
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.2 22 interface Dialer1 22
ip nat inside source static tcp 192.168.0.1 1723 interface Dialer1 1723
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 Dialer1
ip route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
ip route 192.168.30.0 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.254
!
ip access-list extended DEBUG
permit tcp any any eq 1723 log
ip access-list extended NAT
permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 any
permit ip 192.168.1.0 0.0.0.255 any
permit ip 192.168.30.0 0.0.0.255 any
ip access-list extended OUTSIDE_IN
remark CCP_ACL Category=17
permit udp any any eq non500-isakmp
permit esp any any
permit gre any any
permit udp any any eq isakmp log
permit tcp any any eq 1723 log
permit tcp any any eq www
permit tcp any any eq 443
permit tcp any any eq smtp
permit icmp any any
permit tcp any any eq 3389
permit tcp any any eq 22
ip access-list extended SPLIT-TUNNEL
permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
!
access-list 22 remark CCP_ACL Category=16
access-list 22 permit 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
access-list 101 permit ip 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255 192.168.0.0 0.0.0.255
dialer-list 1 protocol ip permit
!
!
!
!
!
snmp-server community kpublic911 RO 22
!
radius server WINDOWS_VPNSERVER
address ipv4 192.168.0.2 auth-port 1812 acct-port 1813
key 7 SharedKey
!
!
!
control-plane
!
!
!
line con 0
exec-timeout 30 0
logging synchronous
stopbits 1
line aux 0
stopbits 1
line 2
no activation-character
no exec
transport preferred none
transport input all
transport output pad telnet rlogin lapb-ta mop udptn v120 ssh
stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
logging synchronous
rotary 1
transport input telnet ssh
line vty 5 15
logging synchronous
transport input all
!
scheduler allocate 20000 1000
ntp update-calendar
ntp server 192.189.54.33
ntp server 150.101.221.106
ntp server 27.50.91.108
end


INTGATEWAY#
```

Comment: Does any other traffic from your "OUTSIDE_IN" ACL make it through, or is it only port 443 that fails?

EDIT: To clarify, I think your Gi0/1 interface may not be properly processing that ACL, since the Dialer1 interface is assigned the IP address and NAT configuration...but I could be wrong.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

The "OUTSIDE_IN" ACL should be applied to the Dialer interface rather than the Physical Gigabit 0/1 interface.

log in and run the following:

```
enable
configure terminal
interface G0/1
no ip access-group OUTSIDE_IN in
interface Dialer 1
ip access-group OUTSIDE_IN in
exit
```

I would recommend having a consultant take care of your DMVPN, ACL rules, and static NAT. Just by looking at your configuration I can tell that you may need some security specialist help.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for answering, and welcome to NE.  I edited out the credentials at the bottom of your answer, since that information should be included on your "about" page in your user profile